# How do i specify a type for a new column through a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a new view from an existing table which as 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE writers (
  movie_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES movies,
  person_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES people,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id,person_id)
) ;
```

I'm trying to make a view which adds a new column and a default character value so I want a the new to have the columns  movie_id, person_id, position_name  and I need position_name to be of type character so that I can union this view with another view.

currently I do:

```
create view test as select movie_id, person_id, "hello" as Statement from writers;
```

but the type of statement is unknown and complicates things for union clauses.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CAST()` your constant in the view creation:

```
create view test as select movie_id, person_id, CAST("hello" AS CHAR) as Statement from writers;
```